# d3.js - dragmove circle with v6 not work as expected

Tags: d3.js

I am learning [this](http://chrome-extension://lkfkkhfhhdkiemehlpkgjeojomhpccnh/index.html) v3 example code and it works fine, but after modify it for v6, I got it running but the second time move the same circle coordinate will not match the mouse position any more!

```js
console.clear()
console.log("======")
//connect_arrow()
drag_move()
function drag_move() {
  var w = 600,
      h = 400,
      r = 25;

  var data = [{x: 50, y: 50}, {x: 150, y: 150} ];

  var drag = d3.drag();

  //drag.subject(Object)
  drag.on('start', dragstart)
  drag.on('end', dragend)
  drag.on('drag', dragmove)

  var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h)
  .style('border','2px solid');

  d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "circle_id")
    .text("Circle ID: ");

  d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "x_var")
    .text("X: ");
  d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "y_var")
    .text("Y: ");

  d3.select("#circle_id")
    .append("span")
    .attr("id", "circle_id_text");

  d3.select("#x_var")
    .append("span")
    .attr("id", "x_coord");
  d3.select("#y_var")
    .append("span")
    .attr("id", "y_coord");

  svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', r)
    .attr('cx', (d)=> d.x)
    .attr('cy', (d)=> d.y)
    .attr('id', (d,i)=> ("circle_" + i))
    .call(drag);

  // Functions

  var circle;
  var circleID;

  function dragstart(d){
    circle = d3.select(this);
    if (circle.attr('id') === 'circle_0'){
      circle.style('fill','red');
    } else {
      circle.style('fill', 'blue');
    }
  }

  function dragend(d){
    d3.select('#circle_id_text')
      .text(null);
    d3.select('#x_coord')
      .text(null);
    d3.select('#y_coord')
      .text(null);
    d3.select(this)
      .style('fill','black');
  }

  function dragmove(d,event){
    circle = d3.select(this);
    circleID = circle.attr('id');
    d.x = Math.max(r, Math.min(w-r, event.x))
    d.y = Math.max(r, Math.min(h-r, event.y))
    d3.select('#circle_id_text').text(circleID);
    d3.select('#x_coord').text(d.x); 
    d3.select('#y_coord').text(d.y);
    circle.attr('cx',d.x).attr('cy',d.y)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dragmove parameter should be (event,d), not (d,event)!

```js
console.clear()
console.log("======")
//connect_arrow()
drag_move()
function drag_move() {
  var w = 600,
      h = 400,
      r = 25;

  var data = [{x: 50, y: 50}, {x: 150, y: 150} ];

  var drag = d3.drag();

  //drag.subject(Object)
  drag.on('start', dragstart)
  drag.on('end', dragend)
  drag.on('drag', dragmove)

  var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h)
  .style('border','2px solid');

  d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "circle_id")
    .text("Circle ID: ");

  d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "x_var")
    .text("X: ");
  d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "y_var")
    .text("Y: ");

  d3.select("#circle_id")
    .append("span")
    .attr("id", "circle_id_text");

  d3.select("#x_var")
    .append("span")
    .attr("id", "x_coord");
  d3.select("#y_var")
    .append("span")
    .attr("id", "y_coord");

  svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', r)
    .attr('cx', (d)=> d.x)
    .attr('cy', (d)=> d.y)
    .attr('id', (d,i)=> ("circle_" + i))
    .call(drag);

  // Functions

  var circle;
  var circleID;

  function dragstart(d){
    circle = d3.select(this);
    if (circle.attr('id') === 'circle_0'){
      circle.style('fill','red');
    } else {
      circle.style('fill', 'blue');
    }
  }

  function dragend(d){
    d3.select('#circle_id_text')
      .text(null);
    d3.select('#x_coord')
      .text(null);
    d3.select('#y_coord')
      .text(null);
    d3.select(this)
      .style('fill','black');
  }

  function dragmove(event,d){
    circle = d3.select(this);
    circleID = circle.attr('id');
    d.x = Math.max(r, Math.min(w-r, event.x))
    d.y = Math.max(r, Math.min(h-r, event.y))
    d3.select('#circle_id_text').text(circleID);
    d3.select('#x_coord').text(d.x); 
    d3.select('#y_coord').text(d.y);
    circle.attr('cx',d.x).attr('cy',d.y)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```